# How do I change my function to pass by reference for my y variable from data it takes in from an input file?

Tags: c++, file-io

Our project is to take binary numbers from an input file and then convert them to there decimal equivalent. I created the input file in jGrasp since that is the compiler I am using. If a space is before the number, then you ignore it and continue until there is a number. If there is a space inbetween the numbers it prints out an error message. I had it working somewhat except in my functions I was using cin.ignore, and now when I changed it to fcin.ignore it gives me an error message. My teacher said to change my function to pass by reference and that would fix it, but im not sure how I would do that. Any suggestions?

```
//input file
   111101\n
1101\n
11  001\n
111000000000000011101010101010101010100\n


//Program
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main( ){
   // vairables
   char ch;
   int decimal = 0;

   //function prototypes
   void decimalValue (char , int&);



   //declaring filestream
   string fileName;
   ifstream fcin;

   //asking user for file name
   cout << "What is the file called: "<< endl;
   cin >> fileName;

   fcin.open(fileName.c_str());
   fcin.get(ch);
   while (!fcin.eof()){ 

      //fcin.get(ch);
      decimalValue(ch,decimal);
      fcin.get(ch);
    }  // end while
    cout << decimal << endl; 
   fcin.close();

return 0;
}

//functions
void decimalValue( char x, int& y ){
   void improperInput(char , int&);
   if (x == '1'){
      y = ((y *2)+1);
      }
   else if (x == '0'){
      y = (y *2);
      }
   else if (x == '\n'){
      cout << y << endl;
      y = 0;
   }
   else if (x == '2')
      improperInput(x,y);
   else if (x == '3')
      improperInput(x,y);
   else if (x == '4')
      improperInput(x,y);
   else if (x == '5')
      improperInput(x,y);
   else if (x == '6')
      improperInput(x,y);      
   else if (x == '7')
      improperInput(x,y);   
   else if (x == '8')
      improperInput(x,y);
   else if (x == '9')
      improperInput(x,y);
   else if ((y == 0) && (x == ' '))
      fcin.ignore();
   else if ((y != 0) && (x == ' '))
      improperInput(x,y);
}

void improperInput(char x, int& y ){
      fcin.ignore(50,'\n');
      cout << "*Improper Input*" << endl;
      y = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like a homework assignment, so I won't just answer directly but leave some things as exercises for the student.

Passing by reference is what you're already doing with `int& y`.  You would also need to understand *what* to pass by reference.

What do you mean by 'it prints out an error message'?  What is the error message?  What is 'It'?  These are important things to be able to tell somebody when asking for help.

If it's a compiler error message, you should try to read and understand what it means.  For example, I would expect to see errors like

```
error: 'fcin' was not declared in this scope.
```

Please do the appropriate research into what 'scope' means and how it applies to variables in a c++ program.